# ROS_PACKAGE_PATH issue. Need help in setting .bashrc

Tags: bash, ros, slam

I have added

```
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH="/home/kathir/ORB_SLAM":${ROS_PACKAGE_PATH}
```

in `.bashrc` and I am getting this error during `cmake` of `ORB_SLAM`.

```
ORB_SLAM cloned path : "/home/kathir/ORB_SLAM"
```

I have another workspace in `"/home/kathir/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash"` in the .`bashrc` since I was using `ROS` for `ARDRONE`.

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/ros/core/rosbuild/private.cmake:102 (message):
  [rosbuild] rospack found package "ORB_SLAM" at "", but the current
  directory is "/home/kathir/ORB_SLAM".  You should double-check your
  ROS_PACKAGE_PATH to ensure that packages are found in the correct
  precedence order.
```

check below for further info

```
kathir@kathir-VirtualBox:~/ORB_SLAM/build$ source .bashrc
bash: .bashrc: No such file or directory
kathir@kathir-VirtualBox:~/ORB_SLAM/build$ $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
bash: /opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks:M$:: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Did you do `source .bashrc` after adding the line with `export`?

Comment: Is `/home/kathir/ORB_SLAM` already in your `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`?  Put `echo "$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH"` just before the `export` and see what you get.

Comment: @Inian : Please check the latest edit.

Comment: @cxw  : I am getting the Indigo's path

Comment: @Kathir : It should be source ~/.bashrc

Comment: Thanks @Inian it works now :-) missed running that. can you explain why do we have to run source ~/.bashrc. Is it like setting environment variable ?

Comment: @Inian Write it as an answer. I ll close this question.

Comment: @Kathir: I have written it as the answer. Don't forget to upvote/accept the answer to mark it closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *error* you are likely seeing is because of your exported variables not taking effect in your current shell. You need it to `source` it in the current shell for it to take effect,

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

or more simply just

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

which imports all the new environment variables to the existing session. You don't have do this for subsequent sessions, as this will be sourced for every new session opened upon startup.

Answer (score 0):

source ~/.bashrc should be used to make the package path effective

Answer (score 0):

if you have add the path and write it to the .bashrc, you can:

run the script: source ～/.bashrc as said by the other answer;

or reopen the terminate, next everytime you open terminal, the script will run automatically